# Laptop CPU and RAM usage

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu-usage, memory-management

For the past two days my laptop has been using way too much RAM and CPU even when I am not using my computer and/or have 1 window open.

Here is a picture of my performance tab:

[image]

Any idea why I am getting this?
I tried searching online  but nothing seems to help me with my problem..

*Keep Note : This is the kind of performance I get 5-10 minutes after launching my laptop, I have no other windows open and I automatically get really high CPU and memory usage.*

Here are my processes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the CPU/Memory usage and share it: http://pastebin.com/peqLGxSa

Comment: have you captured the xperf trace?